# Using a .bat to edit another file

Tags: batch-file

I would like to know how to use a .bat file to edit another file in the same folder.

in example, i am currently working on a text based game.

i would like to have a main file (.bat) to edit specific lines on another file (if possible another .bat)

an example i just made up

File 1:

```
@echo off
echo Change stats +1 to all stats
echo press 1
set /p choice=
if %choice% == goto chstats
pause
:chstats
```

(what i need would go here)

File2:

```
@echo off
set atklvl= 1
set deflvl= 1
echo Player Stats
echo Attack: %atklvl%
echo Def: %deflvl%
pause
```

Comment: Looks like @tim has the right idea.  This is reeeeeally bad, but I used to work at a place that would not allow us to download sed versions for windows and same with perl, leaving us with DOS and my text editor vim.  I used DOS to open file in vim and immediately send commands to vim, via command line arguments, and write and quit, utilizing it as if it was sed or something.  Really bad, but only tool I had for some really complicated text parsing and substitution ( more than just inserting on particular line of file - basically if you're locked up in a box and have only dos and vim, lol )

Comment: Something to edit in your code, the 5th line down (the if statement) doesn't have a second condition. For example, instead of writing if %choice% == 1 goto chstats you wrote if %choice % == goto chstats . This would cause the code to execute if the choice variable had a value of "goto" and then run the command "chstats". Might want to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily write text to another file from within a dos batch file. Try putting this simple example text in a `test.bat` file. This will create a two-line output file named `test.txt`. The first line will contain `aaaa`. The second line will contain `bbb bbb`.

```
echo aaaa > c:\test.txt
echo bbb bbb >> c:\test.txt
```

If what you need to do is very simple this can work well. If not, you might want to try another scripting language like Python or Windows PowerShell.